# Using addError on object in trigger for custom validation messages is taking users to random Picklist Value Sets page in Lightning?

Tags: apex, trigger, visualforce-component, validation

I have a page for a custom object that contains a link:

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="actionLink" 
  onclick="return confirm('{!$Label.PCE_Are_You_Sure}');" 
  action="{!URLFOR($Action.PCE_Step__c.Delete,item.step.id,[retURL=def.id],false)}" 
  value="{!$Label.PCE_Delete}" 
  rendered="{!AND($ObjectType.PCE_Step__c.deletable, canDelete)}"/> 
    <apex:outputtext escape="false" rendered="{!And($ObjectType.PCE_Step__c.deletable, canDelete)}">
  </apex:outputtext>`
```

That handles deleting another custom object that is displayed in a table on the parent objects page.

When that commandlink is clicked, my trigger will add errors if need be.

```
for(CustomObj a : triggerData){
    if(problemBSD.contains(a.Definition__c)){
        a.addError(System.Label.PCE_Parent_Definition_Must_Have_Root_Level_Step.replace('{{def}}',Schema.SObjectType.PCE_Definition__c.label).replace('{{Step}}',Schema.SObjectType.PCE_Step__c.label).replace('{{Stage}}',Schema.SObjectType.PCE_Stage__c.label));
    }
}
```

When this happens (the error gets added to the object), the user is redirected to a Picklist Value Sets page in the Setup... Which appears to be what /setup/own/deleteredirect.jsp takes them to and since there was an error message, it stuck there.

[image]

I cannot get the retURL in the commandLink to work. I just want to take users back to the parent object page (def.Id), but it just keeps going to this picklist value sets page.

How might I be able to control where users are redirected when validation errors are found and added in a trigger? Or perhaps doing .addError on the object cannot be done in the trigger or else this happens?